# iOS:change the starting index of UITableView from 0 to 1 to display array content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

i am using `UITableView` in my project with 2 `ProtoTypeCells`. I have an `array` of main content which i want to display from 2nd `Prototypecell` i.e. from `index` 1.
currently i am using the following code which hide the item at 0 `index` of my `array` and start from first `index` of `array`.
someone please help me how i show the content of dataArray from the index 1 of my tableview.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [DataArray count];
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int feedIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length]-1];
    NSLog(@"Feed Index -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- %d",feedIndex);
    //Feed *item = [[[[self selectedButton] category] feedsList] objectAtIndex:feedIndex + 1];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"OneCellId";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"OtherCellId";

    if(feedIndex == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] ;
            [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:1];
        }
            UIImageView * imgvw = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
            imgvw.layer.cornerRadius = imgvw.frame.size.width / 2;
            imgvw.clipsToBounds = YES;
            imgvw.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profileImg]];
            imgvw.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            [self hideLoadingView];
            return cell;
        //cell.feed = item;
    }
    else 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 ] ;
            [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setTag:2];
        }

        NSString* OtherNameStr = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"full_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",OtherNameStr);
        UILabel * OtherNameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        OtherNameLbl.text = OtherNameStr;
```

here is my screenshot at 0 index i am showing other thing and from index 1 i want to display DataArray from 0 index.

[image]

Comment: Just put the condition 

If(indexPath.row == 0){
return nil;
}
else{
rest of your code
}

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Are you having issues writing `[DataArray count]-1` and `[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best solution in your case is using sections or even section headers.

For solution with sections the first section should show your "header" and the second section your cells. Something like this should work:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0: return 1;
        case 1: return DataArray.count;
        default: return 0;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"OneCellId";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"OtherCellId";

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: {
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1]; // Try having "MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequ..."
            ///...
            return cell;
        }
        case 1: {
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2]; // Try having "MyOtherTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequ..."
            ///...
            NSString* OtherNameStr = [DataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"full_name"];
            ///...
            return cell;
        }
        default: return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]; // This should never happen
    }

}
```

**EDIT: (unrelated) Creating concrete cell class and using height constraints**

You should be having concrete class for instance for your table view cell:

Header:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *profileImage;

@end
```

Source:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *profileImageViewHeightConstraint;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)setProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
    self.profileImageView.image = profileImage;
    self.profileImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = profileImage == nil ? 0.0 : 100.0;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
- (UIImage *)profileImage {
    return self.profileImageView.image;
}

@end
```

You need to set this class in your storyboard and connect both outlets `profileImageView` and `profileImageViewHeightConstraint` with corresponding elements.

Now you can use it in your code as:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
```

And you have all you need exposed so you can simply call:

```
cell.profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

The rest should be accomplished internally. As you can see the setter is overridden and constraint will change depending if image view exists or not. As you requested, it will have 0 if no image is passed, otherwise 100.

Comment: can you please help me how can i change the height of imageview dynamically using constraint as if image available then hight will be 100 otherwise height will be 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this one I just change your code, hope it will help you.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
       return 1;
     }


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [DataArray count]+1;
}


    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"OneCellId";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"OtherCellId";

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 
         forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:1];

            UIImageView * imgvw = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
            imgvw.layer.cornerRadius = imgvw.frame.size.width / 2;
            imgvw.clipsToBounds = YES;
            imgvw.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
            URLWithString:profileImg]];
            imgvw.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            [self hideLoadingView];
            return cell;
    }
    else 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 
         forIndexPath:indexPath];
 [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:2];

        NSString* OtherNameStr = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:
        (indexPath.row)-1]valueForKey:@"full_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",OtherNameStr);
        UILabel * OtherNameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        OtherNameLbl.text = OtherNameStr;

        return cell;
     }
     return nil;
    }
```

Comment: can you please help me how can i change the height of imageview dynamically using constraint as if image available then hight will be 100 otherwise height will be 0